# Option clash for package xcolor and undefined xcolor error

Tags: graphics

so I have been trying to solve for a long time and after a lot of googling I couldn't find the problem (LaTeX noob). I'm basically trying to draw the following (the one from @Bernard):
[Drawing Dijkstra algorithm on a graph without adding it as a image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404952/drawing-dijkstra-algorithm-on-a-graph-without-adding-it-as-a-image/404971#404971)

and I'm getting the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 
     
The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]
Adding the global options:
  ,dvipsnames,table,xcdraw
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
Line 21: 
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Gainsboro'.
See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.270 ...lstyle = solid, fillcolor = Gainsboro!60}
                                                  
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Line 270: 
$ \psset{mnode=Circle, radius = 0.25cm}\psset{fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = Gainsboro!60}
```

This is the part of my code where the problem is happening:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphics}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\title{FUN- Assignment2}
\author{xxxxxx}
\date{December 2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\textbf{Exercise 6)}

\psset{arrowinset=0.12, arrows =->, shortput = nab}
$ \psset{mnode=Circle, radius = 0.25cm}\psset{fillstyle = solid, fillcolor =       
 Gainsboro!60}
\def\pscolhooki{\psset{fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = SteelBlue}}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=1.5cm, rowsep = 1cm]
& [name = t] 2 & [name = v] ∞ \\
[name = s]\textcolor{white}{0} & & & [name = x] ∞ \\
& [name = u]8 & [name = w]∞
%%% labels and arrows
\psset{labelsep = 2pt}
\foreach \T/\W in {v/6,w/3,u/5}{\ncline{t}{\T}\naput{\W}}
\ncline{v}{x}²
\ncline{w}{x}₇
\ncline{w}{u}₁
%%
\psset{fillstyle = none, arcangle = -20}
{\psset{border = 2pt, bordercolor = Gainsboro}
  \ncarc{s}{t}₂
  \ncarc{s}{u}₈}
\ncarc{u}{s}⁸
\ncarc[nodesep= 0pt]{v}{w}\nbput{5}
\ncarc{w}{v}\nbput{4}
\ncarc[arcangle = -65]{v}{s}\nbput[npos = 0.7]{1}
% \nccurve{linecolor = red}{v}{s}
\psset{labelsep = 1em}
\foreach \L in {s, t, u}{\uput[l](\L){\L\strut}}
\foreach \L in {v, w, x}{\uput[r](\L){\L}}
  \end{psmatrix} $

   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as supplement to [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) answer:

- you not need to load `graphics`, it is already load by `graphicx` package
- with `\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}` you not need to load `colortbl`
- in image you use color `Gainsboro` which is defined with `svgnames`
- why you load `tikz` package if you not use it?

considering comments above, your example become:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,xcdraw, table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array,multirow,%graphics
            }
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
%\usepackage{colortbl}

\title{FUN- Assignment2}
\author{xxxxxx}
\date{December 2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\textbf{Exercise 6)}

\psset{arrowinset=0.12, arrows =->, shortput = nab}
$ \psset{mnode=Circle, radius = 0.25cm}\psset{fillstyle = solid, fillcolor =
 Gainsboro!60}
\def\pscolhooki{\psset{fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = SteelBlue}}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=1.5cm, rowsep = 1cm]
& [name = t] 2 & [name = v] ∞ \\
[name = s]\textcolor{white}{0} & & & [name = x] ∞ \\
& [name = u]8 & [name = w]∞
%%% labels and arrows
\psset{labelsep = 2pt}
\foreach \T/\W in {v/6,w/3,u/5}{\ncline{t}{\T}\naput{\W}}
\ncline{v}{x}²
\ncline{w}{x}₇
\ncline{w}{u}₁
%%
\psset{fillstyle = none, arcangle = -20}
{\psset{border = 2pt, bordercolor = Gainsboro}
  \ncarc{s}{t}₂
  \ncarc{s}{u}₈}
\ncarc{u}{s}⁸
\ncarc[nodesep= 0pt]{v}{w}\nbput{5}
\ncarc{w}{v}\nbput{4}
\ncarc[arcangle = -65]{v}{s}\nbput[npos = 0.7]{1}
% \nccurve{linecolor = red}{v}{s}
\psset{labelsep = 1em}
\foreach \L in {s, t, u}{\uput[l](\L){\L\strut}}
\foreach \L in {v, w, x}{\uput[r](\L){\L}}
  \end{psmatrix} $

\end{document}
```

and gives:

[image]

however, considering my answer to [your question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404952/drawing-dijkstra-algorithm-on-a-graph-without-adding-it-as-a-image), you will cut compilation time to about 1/4. with some adoption of answer to your mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,xcdraw, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, hhline, multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, positioning, quotes}

 \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\title{FUN- Assignment2}
\author{xxxxxx}
\date{December 2017}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\textbf{Exercise 6)}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 22mm and 24mm,
every state/.append style = {inner sep=0pt, fill=gray!10,
                             minimum size=7mm},
every edge/.style = {draw, -Triangle, bend angle=15},
                auto=right,
                        ]
    \clip   (-0.4,-3.1) rectangle + (9.7,7.7);%%% <--- added for removing spurious white space above image
\node (s1) [state,fill=gray!50]         {0};
\node (s2) [state, above right=of s1]   {2};
\node (s3) [state, right=of s2]         {$\infty$};
\node (s4) [state, below right=of s3]   {$\infty$};
\node (s5) [state, below  left=of s4]   {$\infty$};
\node (s6) [state, left=of s5]          {8};
%
\draw[gray!30, line width=5pt]
        (s1) to                     (s2)
        (s1) to [bend right=15]     (s6);

%
\draw   (s1) edge ["2"]             (s2)
        (s1) edge [bend right,"8"]  (s6)
        (s2) edge ["6"]             (s3)
        (s2) edge ["3"]             (s5)
        (s2) edge ["5"]             (s6)
        (s3) edge [out=135, in=90,looseness=1.5, "1"]  (s1)
        (s3) edge ["2"]             (s4)
        (s3) edge [bend right,"5"]  (s5)
        (s5) edge [bend right,"4"]  (s3)
        (s5) edge ["7"]             (s4)
        (s5) edge ["1"]             (s6)
        (s6) edge [bend right,"8"]  (s1);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

you will obtain:

[image]

if you like to have different (more colorful) coloring of state nodes, it is simple replace used `gray` colors used in `state` definition and use with desired ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i indeed use other packages but for the rest of the file which i didn't copy here

Answer (score 5):

Package `xcolor` was already loaded by package `tikz` without options. LaTeX allows several `\usepackage` statements for the same package, but it does load the package only once (the first time). Less options in further `\usepackage` commands are no problem. But LaTeX complains, if it sees new options as in this case.

Solution:

Just load `xcolor` before `tikz`:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an xcolor problem and following the gist of @Heiko-Oberdiek's answer I just put my `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` line to the top of my `\usepackage{...}` commands and that worked.